# What's wrong with this R function deriving area of each shape?

Tags: r, function

```
area<-function(...){
 x<-c(...)
 cat("It is area of: ", x[1])
 if (x[1]=="triangle"|1) {
   cat("the baseline is: ", x[2])
   cat("the height is: ", x[3])
   cat("Area equals to ",(x[2]*x[3])/2)
 } 
 if (x[1]=="square"|2) {
   cat("the baseline is ", x[2])
   cat("the height is: ", x[3])
   cat("the area is ",x[2]*x[3])
 }
}

area(1,4,2)
```

What is wrong with this function? I am trying to make a function here which should show up the result of areas for triangles, squares in R. Please help me out with the errors.

Comment: The syntax `(x[1]=="triangle"|1)` is wrong. You could do `(x[1] == "triangle" | x[1] == 1)`

Comment: Thank you for kind comment, but does x<-c(...) have no problem? Console is keep printing out that it is unexpected one.

Comment: Julia, if you use the expression `x <- c(...)` interactively (in console) you will get an error (`Error: '...' used in an incorrect context`) but it works fine in your function. The ellipsis `...` is special and is only defined in scope within a function body that has `...` as an argument. When you send an individual line to the REPL, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that could be improved here. The main issue is that your syntax is wrong; you can't do `if(x[1] == "square"|2)`. You would need to do something like `if(x[1] == "square" | x[1] == 2)` . However, even this is problematic. If your first argument is a string (e.g. if you called `area("triangle", 2, 3)` then the `c(...)` line would convert the 3 entries into a character vector, so the maths operations wouldn't work.

You also have unnecessary repetition in your code, which can be a source of errors.

Finally, your `cat` calls don't have line breaks, which makes the output messy.

Putting these changes together, here is a reproducible example of how the function might work:

```r
area <- function(...){
 x <- c(...)
 area <- x[2] * x[3]
 if (x[1] == 1)  area <- area / 2
 cat("It is area of:", c("triangle", "square")[x[1]])
 cat("\nThe baseline is:", x[2])
 cat("\nThe height is:", x[3])
 cat("\nArea equals to", area)
}

area(1, 4, 2)
#> It is area of: triangle
#> The baseline is: 4
#> The height is: 2
#> Area equals to 4
```

A better, more idiomatic way to do it would be to use named parameters instead of `c(...)`. This makes it much easier to keep the correct types. For example, the following function is much easier to read and understand, and allows numbers or strings to be passed as the first argument:

```r
area <- function(shape, base, height){
 if(is.numeric(shape)) shape <- c("triangle", "square")[shape]
 area <- base * height
 if (shape == "triangle")  area <- area / 2
 cat("It is area of:", shape)
 cat("\nThe baseline is:", base)
 cat("\nThe height is:", height)
 cat("\nArea equals to", area)
}

area(1, 4, 2)
#> It is area of: triangle
#> The baseline is: 4
#> The height is: 2
#> Area equals to 4

area("triangle", 4, 2)
#> It is area of: triangle
#> The baseline is: 4
#> The height is: 2
#> Area equals to 4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! However, in this case, I should also derive the area of  triangle even when I do the calculation by area('triangle', 4, 2). So is it impossible to make function this way?

Comment: @JuliaKim it's not impossible. See my update

Comment: Thank you for the updates, it helped me a lot. Actually, I'm curious whether I can expand this function to derive the areas of circles and trapezoids which are having different numbers of arguments.

Comment: @JuliaKim yes, you can do that. What arguments would you want these shapes to have?

Comment: It's quite similar. So for the case of circles, area(circle, 3) should show the result of 3^2*pi, while area(trapezoid, 2,3,4) should show ((2+3)*4)/2